# Getting response in return to use it further in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
 jQuery.ajax({
 url:'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=Hello&method=POST',
 dataType:'script',
 success:function(){
```

How do I get the response in return to use it further in Javascript?
Please Help Anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're half-way there already. The docs for the jQuery.ajax method explain that the `success` option defines a function to be executed when the request is successful, and that it will receive the response as its first parameter.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=Hello&method=POST',
  success:function(response) {
      // This will display the actual response in your console (e.g. FireBug)
      // Note that jQuery may attempt to format the response into an object (if it receives JSON or XML for instance)

      console.log(response);

      // Do stuff with the response
  }
});
```

It's possible you may be running into some trouble with your `dataType: 'script'` setting. That tells jQuery to try and execute the response data as though it were valid Javascript. Maybe that's what you want, but it sounds to me like you just want to use the data.

Personally, I feel it's good practice to always declare the dataType explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url:'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=Hello&method=POST',
  dataType:'script',
  success:function(response) {
    // use repsonse here. For example:
    alert(response);
  }
});
```